# libmagick equivalent of TIFFReadRGBAImage

Tags: c++, image-processing, imagemagick, libtiff

High.
I was trying to find a well written API documentation for libmagick[++] to get a raster memory block for RGB[A] image data. Something equivalent to [this guide](http://libtiff.maptools.org/libtiff.html#tiffrgbaimage) or at least well documented classes, methods and properties.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Edit:solved:

```
void Magick::Image::write(Blob *blob_,
    const std::string &magick_,
    const unsigned int depth_);
```

Comment: Can you please post the solution as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
void Magick::Image::write(Blob *blob_,
    const std::string &magick_,
    const unsigned int depth_);
```